# What is the best way to save the results that my app generates to use them next time I open my app?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am making simple app for android using python and kivy. My app generates certain results. And those are regular variables. My question is what is the best way to save those results so I could have some sort of history of my results?

Comment: Some useful info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029380/kivy-and-android-sharedpreferences

Comment: sqlite and shared preferences those are your options imo

Comment: check the answer below

Comment: Thank you all, I used Sqlite and it's exactly what I wanted + it's super easy!

Answer (score 0):

Save value to shared preferences or sqlite or file:

for share preferences guide  visit:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

for sqlite guide visit :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

For storage options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html